# Javascript for Two Bootstrap carousels on a page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have almost no Javascript talent. Both of my carousels work with this Javascript on a page, but not with both carousels on a page.

```
jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('.carousel').carousel({interval: 5000});
     jQuery(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
     jQuery(".carousel-inner .carousel-item:first").addClass("active");
});
```

How would I modify this block of code to work with two carousels on a page? My two instances of the Bootstrap 4 carousel are id: #basic-carousel and #wide-carousel.

Comment: One thing I did in a similar situation was to wrap each carrouser (in your case) with a div with a different id. And then relate all the jquery to the $(#randomid).find('.carousel'). Where it says carousel it is really the selector you need as you set in your question.

Comment: Something like this?
      $(#wide-carousel).find('.carousel') {
      jQuery('.carousel').carousel({interval: 5000});
      jQuery(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
      jQuery(".carousel-inner .carousel-item:first").addClass("active");
       });

Comment: I resolved this issue with code from this thread: "Add active class to 2 Bootstrap Carousels on same page with Jquery”.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment this is the equivalent of what I did:

```
jQuery(function(){
     jQuery("#enclosingDiv").find('.carousel').carousel({interval: 5000});
     jQuery("#enclosingDiv").find(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
     jQuery("#enclosingDiv").find(".carousel-inner .carousel-item:first").addClass("active");
});
```

In my case I also set different ids for the .carousel elements but perhaps you don't need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#basic-carousel .carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
    jQuery("#basic-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item:first").addClass("active");
});

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#wide-carousel .carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
    jQuery("#wide-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item:first").addClass("active");
});
```